# Why does this logo move after a postback?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome

I am displaying a logo in the upper right corner of the web page like this:-

```
<div class="tata_logo">
    <img alt="" class="tata_logo" src="..\CommonScripts\logo-mpi-2-white.jpg"/>
</div>
```

with a CSS Style thus:-

```
.tata_logo
{
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    max-width:60px;
    max-height:60px; 
    text-align:right;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

This appears correctly when the screen is first displayed:-

[image]

Then the user of the web page fills in some fields and a postback is performed. After the page is redisplayed the logo has moved down about half an inch:-

[image]

These images were taken from Google Chrome; it works OK on Internet Explorer. Does anyone know what the matter is? What is the approved way of forcing things into the corners of a page?

**Edit** removing the div from the aspx file, and then replacing it appears to have fixed the problem. But I can't really trust it to remain fixed if that sort of thing cures the difficulty. Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: check this link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: use the chrome dom inspector to see what's changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.tata_logo
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align:right;
    max-width:60px;
    max-height:60px; 
    text-align:right;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, and it appeared to work for a while, but now the logo has started moving about again. Thanks for you help, even so.